# Length of curves in curved space via metrics

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

If we have a curve in the plane, we calculate the length as

$\int_{a}^{b} \mid f^{'}(t) \mid dt$

to generalize this to the setting of an arbitrary manifold we define the metric tensor $g$ and the above formula turns into

$\int_{a}^{b} \sqrt{ g(\dot{\gamma},\dot{\gamma})} dt$

for a curve $\gamma$ on a manifold.

I am trying to get the idea behind  this generalization and started to look at the Pythagorean theorem. In the  first,"flat space" case we calculate the length of the tangent via the $dx^{2} + dy^{2}$ and these direction contribute equally. But when the space is curved as say a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ then I assume that these get weighted in some sense. I.e there is a new way of calculating the length of the tangent.

I have hard time seeing and understanding this geometrically. Hence I ask,

Is the above intuition the correct way to understand the idea of a Riemann metric?

And if so, how do I view this geometrically to make sense, for example if I have a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$

In other words is there a way to actually see why the measure of tangent vectors change in the surface and how this is relating the the bending of the surface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think this is the right idea. On a surface inside $\mathbb R^3$, the line element still is $$ds^2=dx^2+dy^2+dz^2.$$

You see different formulas when you introduce *local coordinates* on the surface. For example, consider the paraboloid of equation $z=x^2+y^2$. Then, $dz=2xdx+2ydy$ and so 
$$
dz^2=4x^2dx^2+ 4y^2dy^2 + 4xy(dxdy+dydx).$$
Therefore, the line element on the paraboloid is 
$$\tag{1}
ds^2=(4x^2+1)dx^2 + (4y^2+1)dy^2 + 4xy(dxdy+dydx).$$

In Riemannian geometry, they take this kind of reasoning one step further. A *manifold* is given as an abstract object, that needs not be included in $\mathbb R^3$ or in $\mathbb R^n$. Which implies that there is no $dx^2+dy^2+dz^2$ anymore. You have to **specify** an expression such as (1), which in modern terminology takes the name of *metric tensor*; you do not **compute** it, like we just did here.

Comment: Ah, so the metric tensor dosnt really have to reflect anything about the manifold, it could be rather arbitrary general I suppose, which makes the whole idea of trying to see this from the surface useless?

Comment: Exactly; it can be very much arbitrary.